# NumberFormatExcepcion: For input string:

Tags: arduino, processing, parseint

Hi i´m using Processing with my Arduino to use Serial comunication between them. I have trouble with this part of the code:

```
void draw(){ 

  //read the string.
  pot = arduino.readStringUntil(10);

  //check for null values before casting to int
  if(pot != null){
    num = Integer.parseInt(pot); 

    //draw depending on values
    rect(0,0,100,100);
    text(pot, 0,0);
  }
}
```

The line **num = Integer.parseInt(pot);** always gives me trouble. There is always a problem with the string I use. The las Error Message is **NumberFormatExcepcion: For input string: "111 "** The number at the end is the number i want to read (it is correct). But somehow i cant cast that string into an int. The number int the error message has always a space at the end. I tried to delet it but I can´t. I used **pot = pot.substring(0, pot.length()-1);** and **pot = pot.replace(" ","");**. But it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the trim method from the String class.

```
if(pot != null){
    pot = pot.trim()
    num = Integer.parseInt(pot);
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: Also note that Processing has it's own [int()](http://processing.org/reference/intconvert_.html) conversion method. Both works seamless in this case.